# Why aren't included scripts working on the Android browser?

Tags: javascript, php, html, include, webcam

I have a web page that has to open the webcam. On the PC browser It works, but on the Android browser doesn't work. If I try to open the console debug I see that

It doesn't load the JS files (Only on phone).

Any ideas what the issue is?

```js
  function take_snapshot() {
       //Scatto
       Webcam.snap( function(data_uri) {
        // dove far apparire l'immagine
        document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = 
         '<h2>Sorpreso è:</h2>' + 
         '<img src="'+data_uri+'"/>';
       } );
      }
        
          // WebcamJS v1.0.24 - http://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs - MIT Licensed
     
      Webcam.set({
       width: 320,
       height: 240,
       dest_width: 640,
       dest_height: 480,
       image_format: 'jpeg',
       jpeg_quality: 90
      });
      Webcam.attach( '#my_camera' );
```

```css
 body { font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; }
      h2, h3 { margin-top:0; }
      form { margin-top: 15px; }
      form > input { margin-right: 15px; }
      #results { float:right; margin:20px; padding:20px; border:1px solid; background:#ccc; }
```

```html
  <!doctype html>
    
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
     <title>Test</title>
  
    </head>
    <body>
     <div id="results">Magicamente apparirà qua</div>
     
     <h1>Web-cam Ale culo</h1>
     
     <div id="my_camera"></div>
     
     <!-- libreria per la webcam-->
     <script type="text/javascript" src="webcam.min.js"></script>
     
     <!-- Settaggi della webcam -->
  
     
     <!-- BOTTONE PER CATTURARE -->
     <form>
      <input type=button value="Fota qualcosa" onClick="take_snapshot()">
     </form>

     
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "It doesn't load the JS files" can you post the exact, specifi error you're seeing in the console?

Comment: also, how are you running this on the mobile browser? is it live on a server? is it a cordova/phonegap application?

Comment: Sure, the error is: GET file:///C:/Users/Luca/Desktop/webcam%20test/webcam.min.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: No, in this moment the folders are on my device. In a future the folders will on a remote windows server

Comment: well there's your problem right there... you can't reference a file like that, it must be served with a url, not a local file path. you will have to install wamp or mamp if you want to do scripting. if you want to write local apps for mobile without a server you should check out cordova. both wamp and cordova are free.

Comment: Sure, I will not have this problem on the server. But I have to show this program to a guest and I need to load this file from my device.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

src="webcam.min.js"

by

src="./webcam.min.js"
Maybe paths aren't the same as computer

Comment: Please format your post and not include 'fluff' such as smileys.

Comment: I'm agree with you that the problem is the path, but this isn't  the solution.

Comment: Or maybe try to grab a CDN which can be useful, no path problems, light folder <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/webcamjs/1.0.24/webcam.min.js"></script>

Comment: I can't, the device will not in Internet, only in local. The files will be uploaded on a server.

Comment: Okay, CDN is the best solution, try to create a folder called "js" (without quotes) and drag your "webcam.min.js" in it then put :   <script src="./js/webcam.min.js"></script>

Comment: thanks for trying to be helpful, but if it works on the pc and not on mobile then that conclusively rules out any path problems.

Comment: look into the console, that is the best way to see errors, and post a screenshot if you can, and delete the "type=text/javascript" HTML5 doesn't need it anymore

Comment: The error that i see when i open the file on the device is: 
file:///C:/Users/Luca/Desktop/webcam%20test/webcam.min.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND.
On the PC this message does not appear (obviously)

Comment: You maybe need to serve it with XAMPP(Windows) or LAMP (Linux) for running PHP, or maybe, try to host it on a free web hoster to try, but i also got a question, your mobile "the device will not in Internet", how can you access since your project is on your computer?